# For $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{R}$, prove or disprove that $\exists a \forall b \exists c \forall d\colon ad = bc$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've tried working on this question, but I always get stuck as I am weak when it comes to proving with Quantifiers. How would I approach this question and what steps would I need to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get to pick the value of $a$. Suppose $a \neq 0$, let $b$ be given and $c$ chosen (depending on $b$).

Then the only way the equation is true is if $d = bc/a$. Thus, the only hope we have of the statement being true is if $a=0$.

Then we have that $ad = 0$. So we need either $b=0$ or $c=0$. Here we get to pick $c$. So we can pick $c=0$. Not this did not depend on $b$. So in fact the statement

$$\exists a, c\ \  \forall b, d,\ \ ad = bc$$

is also true.